# Flourless cake didn't set

Tags: baking, cake

I made a cake with butter, eggs, caster sugar and 70% chocolate today. The cooking directions suggest 30 minutes in the oven in a bain marie. I followed the instructions to a tee (as I have done in the past). However, for some reason, the cake didn't set. I left it in the oven for an additional 25 minutes, and then let it rest on the side and cool down for 2 hours. It was still extremely moist and hadn't set as it had done in the past.

I cannot think of anything different that I did. The butter was fresh, the eggs were laid by my own chickens this morning and the chocolate was cooking chocolate.

Is there any way to salvage the cake? The oven doesn't seem to have worked this time!

Comment: Do you have an oven thermometer? Is your oven getting lazy? And for salvaging- that sounds like it would be a great syrup as a topping or to be made into mousse.

Comment: It's a bit more cooked than that (luckily). Just wondering what will finish the cooking off. The oven is only about 8 months old, and is a Gaggenau, so would be really surprised if it's letting me down. I'll check next time I use it.

Comment: Small variations in your ingredients can make a big difference, I'm thinking your eggs. Fresh eggs are great, however they are inconsistent on size. if your eggs were larger than normal it could explain it. I would suggest weighing the egg you use to get a consistent result

Comment: I think you are probably correct @GdD. Next time I will compare egg weights!

Answer (score 1):

One other factor that might've been different, along with size variation in your eggs, is their freshness. Fresh eggs will have a higher water content than older eggs. The other times it set fine, did you use freshly laid eggs?

Comment: When I didn't use fresh eggs, it did set fine. Although as GdD mentioned above, I think that the fresh eggs weigh considerably more than the supermarket ones, which may have caused the issue.